# JSF h:panelGroup inside f:facet does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have extracted this problem out into a simple scenario. obviously I can work around the issue, but curious as to what the explanation might be, and why this does not work.

using h:dataTable as an example, if I put a `<h:panelGroup>` inside one of the `<f:facet>`'s of the table, whats inside the `<h:panelGroup>` does not get displayed, and I dont see why.

this is in a project using Spring, Hibernate and Primefaces with JSF2 and facelets, running on Tomcat, but this appears to be stock standard JSF behaviour?

In the example below, the contents of both h:panelGroup do not get displayed, unless I put an element before the h:panelGroup (for example some text) then it does get displayed?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>-- Nothing --</title>
        </f:facet>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="nothingForm">
        <h:dataTable id="nothingData" value="#{null}" var="item">
           <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header"> col1 </f:facet>
               things
           </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGroup id="headerGroup" rendered="#{true}">
                    crappo
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    col2
                </f:facet>
                stuff
            </h:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:panelGroup id="footerGroup" rendered="#{true}">
                    crappo
                    <h:commandButton id="btn1" value="Button 1" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandButton id="btn2" value="Button 2" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

thanks for looking!

Comment: Are you using JSP or Facelets?

Comment: using facelets, although Im not too sure where this is configured in my application? does Primefaces use facelets by default? Thanks.

Comment: Is your view file JSP or XHTML?

Answer (score 0):

`<f:facet>` must contain a single node, while your `<h:panelGroup>` and the text "col2" are two nodes.
Try moving the text inside of the `<h:panelGroup>`...